# Appending lists in prolog without repetition

Tags: prolog

I need to know how can i get all of combination of appending two lists with each other without repetition  like [1,2] & [3,4] the result will be [1,3] [1,4] [2,3] [2,4]

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? It's pretty simple. Have a look at the `member/2` predicate.

Comment: Hint: *`[X,Y]` is a pair of elements from `L1` and `L2`, respectively, if `X` is a member of `L1` and `Y` is a member of `L2`.*

Comment: yes I've tried but it gave me only [1,3] [2,4] but i need all combinations can you help me please ?

Comment: Could you edit your question and show what you tried?

Comment: comb([],[],[]).
comb([H|T],[X|Y], [H,X]).

comb([H,T|T1], [X,Y|T2], [T,Y]).

comb([H|T], [X|Y], L) :-

                          comb(T, Y, [H|X]).
                       this what i tried

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that does not work as desired:

```
(1) comb([], [], []).
(2) comb([H|T], [X|Y], [H,X]).
(3) comb([H,T|T1], [X,Y|T2], [T,Y]).
(4) comb([H|T], [X|Y], L) :-
        comb(T, Y, [H|X]).
```

(1) says, *Combining an empty list with an empty list is an empty list.* This sounds logically correct.

(2) says, *`[H,X]` is a pair of elements from `[H|T]` and `[X|Y]`*. This is true (provides only one of the combinations for the solution).

(3) says, *`[T,Y]` is a pair of elements from `[H,T|T1]` and `[X,Y|T2]`*. This is also true (provides only one other combination for the solution, different to #2).

(4) says, *`L` is a pair of elements from `[H|T]` and `[X|Y]` if `[H|X]` is a pair of elements from `T` and `Y`*. This can't be true since `L` doesn't appear in the consequent of the clause, so it will never be instantiated with a value.

The above solution is over-thought and more complicated than it needs to be. It fails because it hard-codes two solutions (matching the first two elements and the second two elements). The recursive clause is then faulty since it doesn't have a logical basis, and the solution is left as a singleton variable.

To start, you need to decide what your predicate means. In this particular problem, you can think of your predicate `comb(Xs, Ys, P).` as being TRUE if `P` is a pair (say it's `[X,Y]`) where `X` is from `Xs` (*i.e.*, `X` is a member of `Xs`) and `Y` is from `Ys` (`Y` is a member of `Ys`). Then, when you query your predicate, it will prompt you with each solution until all of them have been found.

This problem can be stated with one rule: *`[X,Y]` is a combination of elements taken from `Xs` and `Ys`, respectively, if `X` is a member of `Xs` and `Y` is a member of `Ys`*. That sounds like a trivially true statement, but it's all you need to solve this problem.

Translating this into Prolog gives this:

```
comb(Xs, Ys, [X,Y]) :-  % [X,Y] is combination of elements from Xs and Ys if...
    member(X, Xs),      % X is a member of Xs, and
    member(Y, Ys).      % Y is a member of Ys
```

Now let's try it:

```
| ?- comb([1,2],[3,4],P).

P = [1,3] ? ;

P = [1,4] ? ;

P = [2,3] ? ;

P = [2,4]

(2 ms) yes
| ?-
```

It found all of the combinations. We let Prolog do all the work and we only had to declare what the rule was.

If you want to collect all the results in a single list, you can use a built-in predicate such as `findall/3`:

```
| ?- findall(P, comb([1,2], [3,4], P), AllP).

AllP = [[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4]]

yes
| ?-
```

And voilà. :)

You can also generalize the solution very easily and choose one element each from each list in a given list of lists. Here, `multicomb/2` has as a first argument a list of lists (*e.g.*, [[1,2], [3,4]]` and generates every combination of elements, one from each of these sublists:

```
multicomb([L|Ls], [X|Xs]) :-
    member(X, L),
    multicomb(Ls, Xs).
multicomb([], []).
```

Which gives:

```
| ?- multicomb([[1,2],[3,4]], P).

P = [1,3] ? a

P = [1,4]

P = [2,3]

P = [2,4]

yes
| ?-
```

And:

```
| ?- multicomb([[1,2],[a,b],[x,y,z]], P).

P = [1,a,x] ? a

P = [1,a,y]

P = [1,a,z]

P = [1,b,x]

P = [1,b,y]

P = [1,b,z]
...
```